# PHP: disregard additional ini files

Tags: php

I have a problem with additional php.ini files being loaded.
I specify the configuration directory to use, but I don't want PHP looking in other places and loading other php.ini or modules. As it turns out, /etc/php.d has modules specified that don't exist, so I always get errors when calling functions.

How can I tell PHP to ONLY look in the place I specified by settings my shell's PHPRC or PHPINIDIR in httpd.conf?

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /home/me/php/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/dbase.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini
```

The error I constantly get is interfering with the JSON string I'm returning to calling functions. The error is:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     
'/home/me/usr/lib64/php/modules/dbase.so' - /home/me/usr/lib64/php/modules/dbase.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

The dbase.so is declared in /etc/php.d, and I can't remove it since we don't have access to system-level settings, and besides, some other user may be relying on the default settings (even tho they are broken).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MikeC, this is a common issue with webhosting shared installations.  The PHP search list is by design, and helps ensure that ISPs can enforce ini includes.  If you don't have access to the system config, then you can't fix it.  This is one to log with the service / support desk of your hosting provider. Point out the error and ask them to remove the ini file from the conf.d directory.

I've had similar problems in the past.

As to "The error I constantly get is interfering with the JSON string I'm returning to calling functions",  why are you returning errors to the user or AJAX routines anyway? Best practice is to log errors to file, so this content shouldn't appear in your JSON returns anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Terry. This is my dev system, and so I have all error reporting turned on. I agree with you that in production those types of errors shouldn't even be seen by users.

Comment: It depends on the ./configure directives when php is built. The --with-config-file-scan-dir option sets the config directory to be scanned - typically `/etc/php.d` or `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`.  This directory is scanned last so these ini filecan override anything that you put in the main ini.

Answer (score 2):

```
poncha@localhost:~$ php -c . -r 'var_dump(function_exists("mysql_connect"));'
bool(true)

poncha@localhost:~$ export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=""
poncha@localhost:~$ php -c . -r 'var_dump(function_exists("mysql_connect"));'
bool(false)
```

The `-c` actually matches `PHPIniDir` apache configuration.
As for the environment variable, you can set it for apache instance (in apache init script for instance), but then it would mean you still need OS level control